# Sorting Algorithm for Round Robin Seeding

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I want to create a program where I put in a list of players, where the first line is the best player, and the last line is the worst player. Then it will do an algorithm, and sort these players into seeded groups of equal skill.

Here's how I want this to work:
Say you have 16 players, and you want 4 groups of players.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

Now you want to sort these into four equal groups:

```
1 8  9 16
2 7 10 15
3 6 11 14
4 5 12 13
```

So the end result of the list would be:

```
1 8 9 16 2 7 10 15 3 6 11 14 4 5 12 13
```

But say you had the same 16 players, but you only want 2 groups, then it would be:

```
1 4 5 8  9 12 13 16
2 3 6 7 10 11 14 15
```

Which would be:

```
1 4 5 8 9 12 13 16 2 3 6 7 10 11 14 15
```

Can someone help me find an algorithm that could do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to print the numbers [boustrophedonically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boustrophedon):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

int size = 16;
int num = 4; // In your example either 4 or 2.
int rowLength = size / num;
List<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i=0;i<size / rowLength;++i) {
  int t = i;
  for (int j=0;j<rowLength / 2;++j) {
    sortedList.add(t+1);
    sortedList.add(t+(2*(num-i)));
    t += 2*num;
  }
}
```

When run with num=4 it prints:

```
[1, 8, 9, 16, 2, 7, 10, 15, 3, 6, 11, 14, 4, 5, 12, 13]
```

When run with num=2 it prints:

```
[1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 16, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15]
```

It runs in O(n) which is as good as you can get for this problem.

Comment: No, he wanted to sort the list.

Comment: When I tried this solution the output was:
[1, 8, 9, 16, 9, 16, 9, 16, 2, 9, 9, 16, 9, 16, 9, 16, 3, 10, 9, 16, 9, 16, 9, 16, 4, 11, 9, 16, 9, 16, 9, 16, 5, 12, 9, 16, 9, 16, 9, 16, 6, 13, 9, 16, 9, 16, 9, 16, 7, 14, 9, 16, 9, 16, 9, 16, 8, 15, 9, 16, 9, 16, 9, 16, 9, 16, 9, 16, 9, 16, 9, 16, 10, 17, 9, 16, 9, 16, 9, 16, 11, 18, 9, 16, 9, 16, 9, 16, 12, 19, 9, 16, 9, 16, 9, 16, 13, 20, 9, 16, 9, 16, 9, 16, 14, 21, 9, 16, 9, 16, 9, 16, 15, 22, 9, 16, 9, 16, 9, 16, 16, 23, 9, 16, 9, 16, 9, 16]

Comment: Oops I meant This walks through the indices in order: diff = rowLength; i = 0; if i + rowLength ok then i = i + rowLength; else if i + 1 ok then { i = i+1; diff = -diff}; else done